# Laravel Backpack uppercase

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-backpack

I am trying to have a column where

- the text is in upper case
- and the column is orderable.

If I am doing this through an accessor, then this won't be a tableColumn and it won't be orderable. So this wont work.

Next I am trying to find a way to make it uppercase in blade?
For example, I am setting a column->toUpper = true;

```
     $this->crud->addColumn(
        [
            'name'      => 'country',
            'label'     => 'Country,
            'type'      => 'text',
            'toUpper'   => true
        ]);
```

Where in blade can I search for this and transform the value?

Or how should I do this? Looks like an easy task but I cant find it in the docs.

**Edit**
Changing this to a modelFunction will disable other functionality like search. So really what we need is to have the field like a db column and retain all the associated functionalities (search sort etc) and make it uppercase in Blade as it is a display issue.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use

```
CRUD::column('text_and_email')
        ->type('model_function')
        ->label('Text and Email')
        ->function_name('getUpperText')
```

And add in model function

```
public function getUpperText() {
    return strtoupper($this->field);
}
```

UPD:

We can change by CSS
We can add custom class to column by use ne

```
 'attributes' => [
       'class' => 'some-class'
 ]
```

and use CSS

```
text-transform: uppercase;
```

Comment: Yep this works. Not sure how calling an attribute makes it not orderable anymore but making it a function is still orderable. It might be that I let the name as the db table in this case. Thanks.

Comment: Now search is not working. It would be more easy and logical to have the possibility to just change this in blade as it is a display thing. We should leave the field as db column and make it uppercase in blade.

Comment: @alextoader I add another solution

Comment: @alextoader and for fixed search by use custom method need add search logic ``` ->searchLogic(function ($query, $column, $searchTerm) {
            $query->orWhere('email', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
            $query->orWhere('text', 'like', '%'.$searchTerm.'%');
        });  ```

Answer (score 0):

You can directly use bootstrap `text-uppercase` class on the column wrapper to get the desired output:

```php
$this->crud->addColumn(
[
  'name'      => 'country',
  'label'     => 'Country,
  'type'      => 'text',
  'wrapper'   => [
    'class' => 'text-uppercase'
  ],
]);
```

Cheers

Answer (score -1):

use Illuminate\Support\Str;

$string = Str::upper('QandeelAcademy');

Use this method when you are fetching the data from the database
[Read this](https://www.qandeelacademy.com/questions/how-to-converts-the-given-string-to-uppercase-in-laravel)

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).